# How to test am image/png result with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, png, cucumber, capybara

Using Capybara I would like to test:

```
visit("/some_dynamic_resource.png")
```

And to test that the returned result is really an image using `page.body` returnes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">
<html>
    <body>
        <p>\x89PNG\r\n\n</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I could see that there is:

```
\x89PNG\r\n\n
```

But I would like get the content of the png and do some testing on it.

Do you know of a way to do this?